# Function programming from a ranking to binary choice matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, ranking

I have some difficulties programming a function in MATLAB. I want to construct a function that converts a given ranking into a binary choice matrix. For example, when 3 options are ranked in a ranking R(3,1,2) the binary choice matrix should be

```
[0 1 0;
 0 0 0; 
 1 1 0]
```

So when element `i` proceeds element `j`, the matrix element `a(i,j)` is `1` and `0` otherwise. Could anyone help me create this function please?

Comment: I think you need to expand on your explanation of how you got to that matrix given `[3,1,2]`. It is not clear at all.

Comment: It's an example, there are 3 options which are ranked. Option 3 is prefered over option 1 and 2, and 1 is prefered over 2. I want to do this with similar rankings of a given length N.

Comment: But how do the numbers 3,2,1 become that binary matrix? Does it have to do with the rows? The columns? You need to explain your mapping properly.

Comment: For a ranking of N options we want to construct a NxN matrix.  Options 1,2,3 represent elements of the ranking. The ranking goes from the most prefered option to the least prefered option. So when the ranking is (3,1,2) it means that option 3 is prefered over option 1 which is prefered over option 2. To construct the matrix, each element of the matrix represents whether option i is prefered over option j. So since 1 is prefered over over 2, element a(1,2)=1. Since 3 is prefered over 1 and 2 elements a(3,1) and a(3,2) give 1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but this seems to do what you want:

```
r = [3 1 2]; %// ranking
[~, s] = sort(r);
M = bsxfun(@gt, s, s.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like.

```
B=zeros(length(R)); %create an nxn matrix
for j=2:length(R)
B(R(1:j-1), R(j))=1;
end
```